# Misfiring jQuery media query

Tags: jquery

Im having a problem getting this bit of script. I need it to run as soon as the window is ready but at the moment it only fires when I slightly reduce the size of the browser window :S

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
if ($(this).width() >= 1280) {
    $(function(){
        $('.img-wrap, .qoute-background') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.img-wrap, .qoute-background') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
        });
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just trigger it once.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(this).width() >= 1280) {
            $('.img-wrap, .qoute-background').css({
                'min-height': (($(window).height())) + 'px'
            });
        }
    }).trigger('resize')
});
```

And clean your DOM ready's a bit to look like above..

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit strange, it should be better like this:

```
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1280) {

        $('.img-wrap, .qoute-background') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.img-wrap, .qoute-background') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
        });

    }
});
```

Even with this changes I'm not sure the code does what it should. I think this is more like what you wish:

```
function updateSize(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 1280) {
       $('.img-wrap, .qoute-background') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
    }
}
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(updateSize);
    updateSize();
});
```

Comment: this works at showing the image but it seems to display at all resolutions. I only need to to run the script when the resolution gets to 1280px or bigger

Comment: still not really having any luck. it works if I refresh my screen and resize but if repeatedly resize it stops working :S

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could create a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gufKb/

whats suppose to be happening is that the image and the dark overlay are meant to take up the full height of the browser window. The thing is I only want that to happen when the browser is at a certain width i.e 960px or greater, when the screen is smaller then 960 I'll be doing something else with the content.

this is what it needs to look like from 960px+
https://www.dropbox.com/s/by65jzz0s6rq99x/Screenshot%202014-07-27%2012.05.18.png

:)